# Datatable (JS) not working with list in R (callback javascript)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

I am trying to plot a table where the cells are colored by:

- **RED** when the value of the cell is lower than the mean of the column
- **LIGHTGREEN** when the value of the cell is greater than the mean of the column

And scaled based on how distant the cell value is from the lowest (or highest) value.

I could already figured out how to do it using the data altogether, i.e., using the mean of the whole table, using the max of the whole table, min of the whole table, and so on.

The code is **not** distinguishing by the mean of the column (using the mean of the whole cells, entire table):

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ab <- as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(runif(50, -1, 1), 3), 10), sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))


vals <- list()

vals$rm = mean(rowMeans(ab))
vals$rr = abs(max(ab)) + abs(min(ab))
vals$r1 = abs(max(ab)) - mean(rowMeans(ab))
vals$r0 = abs(min(ab)) - mean(rowMeans(ab))

string <- paste0("function(row, data) {",
                 paste(lapply(1:ncol(ab),function(i){
                   paste0("var value=Math.abs(data[",i,"]);
                                        var value2=data[",i,"];
                                       if (value!==null){
                                       if(value2 < ",vals$rm,"){
                                       $(this.api().cell(row,",i,").node()).css({'background':isNaN(parseFloat(value)) || value > ",vals$rr," ? '' : 'linear-gradient(90deg, transparent ' + (1 - (",vals$rm," - value2)/",vals$rr,")* 100 + '%, red ' + (1 - (",vals$rm," - value2)/",vals$rr,") * 100 + '%)','background-size':'98% 88%','background-repeat':'no-repeat','background-position':'center'});
                                       }else{
                                       $(this.api().cell(row,",i,").node()).css({'background':isNaN(parseFloat(value)) || value > ",vals$rr," ? '' : 'linear-gradient(90deg, transparent ' +  (1 - (-",vals$rm," + value2)/",vals$rr,") * 100 + '%, lightgreen ' +   (1 - (-",vals$rm," + value2)/",vals$rr,")* 100 + '%)','background-size':'98% 88%','background-repeat':'no-repeat','background-position':'center'});
                                       }
                                       } ") 
                 }),collapse="\n"),
                 "} ")

datatable(ab, options = list(rowCallback=JS(string)))
```

[image: example]

The code that I wished was working:

```r
vals <- list()

for(g in 1:(ncol(ab))) vals$rm[g] = mean((ab[,g]))
for(g in 1:(ncol(ab))) vals$rr[g] = abs(max(ab[,g])) + abs(min(ab[,g]))
for(g in 1:(ncol(ab))) vals$r1[g] = abs(max(ab[,g])) - mean((ab[,g]))
for(g in 1:(ncol(ab))) vals$r0[g] = abs(min(ab[,g]) - mean((ab[,g])))

string <- paste0("function(row, data) {",
                 paste(lapply(1:ncol(ab),function(i){
                   paste0("var value=Math.abs(data[",i,"]);
                                        var value2=data[",i,"];
                                       if (value!==null){
                                       if(value2 < ",vals$rm[i],"){
                                       $(this.api().cell(row,",i,").node()).css({'background':isNaN(parseFloat(value)) || value > ",vals$rr[i]," ? '' : 'linear-gradient(90deg, transparent ' + (1 - (",vals$rm[i]," - value2)/",vals$rr[i],")* 100 + '%, red ' + (1 - (",vals$rm[i]," - value2)/",vals$rr[i],") * 100 + '%)','background-size':'98% 88%','background-repeat':'no-repeat','background-position':'center'});
                                       }else{
                                       $(this.api().cell(row,",i,").node()).css({'background':isNaN(parseFloat(value)) || value > ",vals$rr[i]," ? '' : 'linear-gradient(90deg, transparent ' +  (1 - (-",vals$rm[i]," + value2)/",vals$rr[i],") * 100 + '%, lightgreen ' +   (1 - (-",vals$rm[i]," + value2)/",vals$rr[i],")* 100 + '%)','background-size':'98% 88%','background-repeat':'no-repeat','background-position':'center'});
                                       }
                                       } ") 
                 }),collapse="\n"),
                 "} ")
                   
datatable(ab, options = list(rowCallback=JS(string)))
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the problem with the code you provide at the end? Why don't you use this one?